# Safe way to find images in Word Documents

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I created a simple C# method with the purpose to find out if a Word Document contains an image:

```
public bool ContainsImage(string fileName)
{
   using (var wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, false))
   {
      return wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Graphic>().Any();
   }
}
```

This works with my sample file but I am confused if it works with every docx document.
I researched for solutions to handle images in Word Documents and I found a lot different approaches to detect images:

- `Decendants<Graphic>()` - works as described
- `Decendants<Inline>()` - works too
- `Decendants<Drawing>()` - does not work
- `Decendants<Picture>()` - does not work

What is the correct way? I don't care where an image is located in the document, as long it is visible. It does not matter if it is in the background, in front or between text, etc.
What are the differences between these objects (Graphic, Inline, Drawing, Picture)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By trial and error I came a shorter approach to check for the ImageParts of the different Document parts. And I do additionally check the HeaderParts and FooterParts for images now, because they were not considered before:

```
public bool ContainsImage(string fileName)
{
   using (var wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, false))
   {
      if (wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.ImageParts.Any())
         return true;

      foreach (var header in wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
         if (header.ImageParts.Any())
            return true;

      foreach (var footer in wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts)
         if (footer.ImageParts.Any())
            return true;
  }

   return false;
}
```

I also found a solution where somebody just checked the first item of HeaderParts and FooterParts. I am not sure if this is enough and why would there be more then only the first part.

Comment: Looks good to me :) have you checked if graphics/charts are found with the ImageParts property as well? If they are not found but you need to take those into account aswell,  you might have to just add more conditions in the if statements

Comment: I checked that charts can be found as well. What I still not understand is what you mean with graphics in that case. Whats the difference between a graphic and an image?

Comment: Yes charts is what i meant. Nevermind is a translation issue since english is not my native language.

Comment: Ah okay, for me either. But thank you Jordi!

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve all images and graphics from a Word document using C#, you can use the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` library. Here is a sample code snippet:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public List<Image> GetImages(Document doc)
{
    List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
    foreach (InlineShape shape in doc.InlineShapes)
    {
        if (shape.Type == WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)
        {
            shape.Range.Select();
            doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.CopyAsPicture();
            IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            Image img = (Image)data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
            images.Add(img);
        }
    }
    return images;
}
```

The code I provided extracts all images from a Word document, including those in the background and footer. The code loops through all the inline shapes in the document and extracts the images that are of type wdInlineShapePicture. You can modify this code to extract graphics as well by checking for other types of inline shapes.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It might also be useful to detect charts in my case. The use of my image detection is to decide if a file will be converted to a binary or a greyscale image. So it might also be good to detect a chart and convert it to greyscale instead of binary to cause a lesser loss of information.
Could you explain what the difference between an image and a graphic is in the Word Document context?

Comment: Does Decendants<Inline>() also work if an image is located in the background, footer or elsewhere?

Comment: The difference between a graphic and image is the type of the descendant, now that you clarified your requirements, i would suggest using another approach to get all the images, and graphics.   See my updated answer

Comment: I alreadry tried the approach with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word but it is not possible for different reasons. It is to slow and seems to need an installed Word on the client where it is executed. Therefore I switched to the DocumentFormat.OpenXml library.
Also I do not need the image, just the information if an image exsists.

Comment: I think you can achieve it with  DocumentFormat.OpenXml, looking for <Graphics> descendants in a similar way that the answer provided. To get the images in background and footer you have to explore other parts of the document, because in your code example you are only looking in the MainDocumentPart

Comment: That is true, I realized that by trying with differen file configurations. I add my current approach as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly with how open ended your question is. May be best to utlize all of them. Would require more robust code but considering your requirements may be required.

Comment: I don't want to create complex code if one of those keywords already fits the requirements. I researched for a documentary of the tags Microsoft is using in the XML based format but I could not find an overview. I hoped that somebody here could help.